# how do I configure autowire in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

how do I configure autowire in spring

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the context schema to your configuration XML and use the @Autowired annotation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

Comment: @autowired alone was not enough - exactly what I was missing. thanks.