# Spring - what is wrong with my Autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I've this basic spring application in which the value of my `@Autowired` field is null in output. What is wrong here?

```
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class HelloWorld {
   private String message;

   @Autowired
   private Double pi;

   public HelloWorld(String message){
       this.message  = message;
   }

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }

   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
      System.out.println("autowired: "+pi);
   }
}
```

spring.xml config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="pi" name="pi" class="java.lang.Double" autowire="byName">
        <constructor-arg value="3.14"/>
    </bean>


   <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.spring.HelloWorld">
        <constructor-arg ref="msg" />
   </bean>

    <bean id="msg" class="java.lang.String" >
        <constructor-arg value="Hello World"/>
    </bean>     

</beans>
```

Class to execute the APP:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
      HelloWorld hw =  context.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
      hw.getMessage();
      System.out.println(context.getBean("msg"));



   }
}
```

The output is:

```
Your Message Hello World
autowired: null
Hello World
```

Comment: try having set method and check.

Comment: @KDP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536674/how-does-spring-autowired-work

Comment: in that case there should be a appropriate annotation for class isn't it?

Comment: No luck using a setter

Comment: @ares check the question I linked, spring reflects the setter

Comment: I do hope autowiring a value for Pi is purely a demonstration! Otherwise I'm sure the Spring detractors will have a field day

Comment: @JordiCastilla: I used a correct setter `public void setPi(Double pi)`. Although the question you linked added more insight. Answers [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31159599/2965883) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31161144/2965883) precisely pointed to what I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` in your spring.xml file which will scan for spring annotations in your java files. Hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="pi" name="pi" class="java.lang.Double">
        <constructor-arg value="3.14" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.clsa.test.HelloWorld">
        <constructor-arg ref="msg" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="msg" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="Hello World" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: As a note `<context:component-scan value="package"/>` also worked which I tried after this answer's solution. So it answered my other question why it was working flawlessly in my Spring MVC app.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the context to allow autowiring. See this answer:

[how do I configure autowire in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516704/how-do-i-configure-autowire-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

```
you want to define @Quatifier

@Autowired(required=true)
@Qualifier("pi")
Double pi;
```